# Unable to open file and write in append mode using python

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

My python version is 2.7.3.  I am trying to open a file and write to it. I want to append in file as the write thing is inside a loop. But it actually doesn't write anything. 
The code that I have written is as follows:

```
import os
import re
file = [ "/home/sam/a.cpp" , "/home/sam/b.cpp" ]
fo = open("/home/sam/missingId.txt", 'a')
print os.getcwd()
for imagefile in file :
    f = open(imagefile,'r')
    print imagefile
    f.readline()
    f.readline()
    condition = True
    while condition:
        line1=f.readline().split()
        if line1[0] != "};" :
            line2=f.readline().split()
            search = "\"" + line1[1] +"\""
            os.system("find /home/sam/abcd/ -exec grep " + search + " \'{}\' \\; -print > ~/sam.txt")
            var = os.popen('ls -ltr ../ritesh.txt').read()
            result = [str(x) for x in filter(None, re.split(' ',var))]
            print result
            print result[4]
            if result[4] == "0" :
                fo.write(line1[1])
                print(" Here I am \n")
                fo.write("\n")
                print line1[1]
            line=f.readline().split()
        else :
            condition = False
fo.close()
```

It's going inside the loop as I am getting the the output of `print line1[1]` on the console.

I have a linux environment.

Comment: Have you checked if there is a *new* file `missingId.txt` in the current directory? You are using a relative path to open the file. You may want to add a `import os; print os.getcwd()` call in there to make sure you are in the correct directory.

Comment: Before running the script there is no file missingId.txt Its gets created when I run the script but not gets written there

Comment: Well, there are 2 options: you got something wrong and your loop doesn't run (and you are confused by a different print statement), or `fo` has been replaced by something *else* with a `.write()` method before the loop is run. Impossible to tell without more context from your script.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have update the relevant code for you , I can see the output Here I am which shows its going inside the loop  :)

Comment: You are also not just getting newlines in the file?

Comment: Pro tip: you can `break` out of a loop, no need to use a `while condition:` test when a `while True:` will do. Instead of `condition = False` you use `break` to step out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No I am not even getting a newline in file missingId.txt

Comment: I'd advocate you look at [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) right about now and *test* every assumption by walking through your code. Call `fo.flush()` manually to test what is going on. Your code doesn't show *anything* that would have me believe writing isn't working.